# Java resource bundle formatting with out commas

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle, number-formatting

I have a webservice implementation which validates the request and writes an error message in the response. The response is not in the desired format.

The error message template is in a resource bundle property file.

```
...
key=Plant name {0}  Plant Id {1}.
...
```

This is the error message I get after the validation.

```
Plant name PLANT1  Plant Id 9,905,005.
```

But desired output is with out commas for the numeric variable.

```
Plant name WPLANT  Plant Id 9905005.
```

Here is the code I have.

```java
private String getErrorMessage(String messageKey, Object... args) {
    ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ErrorMessageResourceBundle");
    MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("");
    formatter.applyPattern(messages.getString(messageKey));
    String output = formatter.format(args);
    return output;
}
```

I am calling this method with the key and the variables as below.

```java
...
getErrorMessage(key,"PLANT1",9905005)
...
```

How do I change this code to get the desired output? I prefer a method doesn't contain %s, %d since then I lose the ability to change the order of the variables in my error message in the property file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use subformat pattern.
Example:

```
MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("{0} {1,number,###0}");
```

So the code would be like this:

```
private String getErrorMessage(String messageKey, Object... args) {
    ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ErrorMessageResourceBundle");
    MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("{0} {1,number,###0}");
    formatter.applyPattern(messages.getString(messageKey));

    String output = formatter.format(args);
    return output;
}
```

Read Oracle's documentation about SubFormatPattern here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#patterns

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still it prints the output **with** commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just convert the number to `String` first.

```
getErrorMessage(key,"PLANT1", String.valueOf(9905005))
```

This should work. I suspect that message formatter aauto detects the number and formats it as one, based on your locale.